# Rendering hidden span text inside h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

We have an accessibility requirement to render certain command links with additional "off screen" text for screen readers. So we want to end up rendering something like (attributes omitted for clarity)

```
<a>Edit Details<span class="hiddenOffScreen"> for John Smith</span></a>
```

The problem is the standard jsf1.2 `<h:commandLink>` tag does not respect the `escape` attribute. I tried something like `<h:commandLink escape="false" value="#{linkText}"/>` where linkText evaluates to the contents of the a tag shown above but this renders the span tag literally (i.e escapes the < and >)

How best to go about meeting this requirement? I can of course easily add the span later with JQuery however, for my own education I'd like to have a try with a custom renderer - but not sure how I would hook in with the existing default renderer which adds the "onClick" event handler and associated javascript. My google-foo seems to have failed me when searching for custom commandLink renderer.

Bear in mind, this is JSF 1.2 and we cannot use any third party tag libraries as we're running on a braindead very old version of WebSphere Portal Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest content, including other tags and/or implicit text, within the `<h:commandLink>` tag, instead of specifying text within its `value` attribute, to achieve your functionality:

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <h:outputText .../>
    <span class="hidden"></span>
    #{bean.someText}
</h:commandLink>
```

This will render exactly what you want.

Comment: slaps head. Of course. I forgot that you don't need to use the `value` attribute for a commandLink. Stupid me! :(

Answer (score 0):

Use < or > to write < >

Comment: I think you meant to say use the entity escapes - but that does not work. I do not want to render a literal < on screen I want to render it as an actual span tag which is what the jsf `escape` attribute is supposed to do.